# How to wrap JavaScript span ID at Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I would like to send span id.
I've tried these code at blade file but I couldn't get value.
Could you teach me how to write code please?

```
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<span id="quantity"></span>">
```

and

```
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<span id=&quot;quantity&quot;></span>">
```

**UPDATE**

I wrote this but "quantity" value is this ""

```
const priceAch = comma(parseInt(String(typeValue * productValue * quantity)));
document.getElementById('edit-quantity').value = priceAch;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me if I've misinterpreted your question, but if you're trying to get the HTML value between your span tags to become the value of your hidden input, you could do something along the lines of this:

```
<span id="quantity">23</span>
<input id="edit-quantity" type="hidden">

<script>
    document.getElementById('edit-quantity').value = document.getElementById('quantity').innerText;
</script>
```

This will set the value attribute of your input element to the text located between the span tags. In the above scenario, the input value would return "23".

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. I tried your code but my value is like this "quantity" => "<span id="quantity"></span>". I update my current code. Could you take a look please?

Comment: Sure! Have you happened to change the id of your input to the id you mentioned: "edit-quantity"

`<input id="edit-quantity" type="hidden" name="quantity">`

Comment: @bluetail if you have updated the input id, can you please provide your variable and function references in the following statement so I can try to reproduce the outcome: `comma(parseInt(String(typeValue * productValue * quantity)))`

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked!. I'm so happy. Thank you so much!!!